# omitting bookseries from bibliography as well as notes in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

`biblatex-chicago` includes the `bookseries` option, which can be set to `false` in order to omit the book series of books from the notes (when the `notes` option is turned on). This is a particularly delicate operation because it involves the `series` field, which is used for two very different purposes:

1. the book series (a title like "The Transformation of the Classical Heritage" or "The Cambridge History of Science")
2. a journal's series in `article` bib-entries (a number like "2" for the output "2nd ser.")

Is there a way to extend the `bookseries=false` option so that it omits the book series (and the corresponding number from the `number` field) not only in footnotes *but also in the bibliography*?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes,bookseries=false]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{lindberg.shank2013camb.hist.sci:med.sci,
    Address = {Cambridge},
    Editor = {Lindberg, David C. and Shank, Michael H.},
    Number = {2},
    Publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    Series = {The Cambridge History of Science},
    Title = {Medieval Science},
    Year = {2013}}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

\cite{lindberg.shank2013camb.hist.sci:med.sci}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Current output:

> David C. Lindberg and Michael H. Shank, eds., *Medieval Science* (Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 2013)
>
> **References**
>
> Lindberg, David C., and Michael H. Shank, eds. *Medieval Science*. The Cambridge History of Science 2. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 2013.

Desired output:

> David C. Lindberg and Michael H. Shank, eds., *Medieval Science* (Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 2013)
>
> **References**
>
> Lindberg, David C., and Michael H. Shank, eds. *Medieval Science*. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look in `chicago-notes.cbx` you will find that `cser+num` (used in citations) is defined like this:

```
\newbibmacro*{cser+num}{%
  \iftoggle{cms@bookseries}
    {\printfield{series}%
     \printfield[sernum]{number}}
    {}}
```

Whereas `ser+num` (used in bibliography) is defined as:

```
\newbibmacro*{ser+num}{%
  \printfield{series}%
  \printfield[sernum]{number}}
```

There are a couple of entry types that don't use `ser+num`, but redefining this macro should do what you want in nearly every case.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes,bookseries=false]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{lindberg.shank2013camb.hist.sci:med.sci,
    Address = {Cambridge},
    Editor = {Lindberg, David C. and Shank, Michael H.},
    Number = {2},
    Publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    Series = {The Cambridge History of Science},
    Title = {Medieval Science},
    Year = {2013}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{ser+num}{%
  \iftoggle{cms@bookseries}
    {\printfield{series}%
     \printfield[sernum]{number}}
    {}}

\begin{document}

\cite{lindberg.shank2013camb.hist.sci:med.sci}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: output]